# Como capturar o teclado no pygame durante o jogo, onde háapenas som?

Tags: teclado, pygame

Então pessoal. Sou deficiente visual e estou iniciando agora na programação de jogos, tentando fazer um jogo pygame, mas usando apenas o som. Mas no menu principal eu quero que ao pressionar a seta para baixo ele vá para uma opção "novo jogo", que eu também queria aprender como criar. E ao pressionar esc ele sai do jogo. Como fasso isso? depois de entrar em novo jogo, quero abrir um texto explicando o jogo e depois, o usuário teria que pressionar as setas do teclado para andar no mapa e gostaria de tocar o som dos passos. Mas eu não sei criar mapas, nem  nada. Aqui está meu código

```py
import pygame.mixer
from pygame.mixer import *
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('musica.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
    m=input ('Menu principal, por favor selecione uma opção')
```